# Mysql - Automatically Copy Data from one table to another on a specific date

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to copy data from one table to another on a specific date.  I have a list of names that can be altered by a user.  However, on a certain date, these need to be locked in and copied to a uneditable table and then mailed to key users.

How would I do this?

Cheers

Comment: I'm at the planning stage, pulling tables and data together.  Haven't tried anything yet.  I'm an enthusiastic amateur so just after some advice.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` has `trigger`.

`trigger` is like functions which is called on a specific events and cannot be called explicitly. If the event specified occurs, database automatically calls that `trigger` and does what it supposed to do.

So to do your job, you can write a trigger which will work on your tables and set the date when you want to do your task. Then use `if` to check the system date is your desired date and if yes do your job.

I used trigger on `oracle` and never used on `mysql` but as `triggers` are using `pl/sql`, there should be no difference between `trigger`s of `oracle` and `mysql`.

`PHP` has `Mail` sending options. You can send mail using `php`.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That's great.  I'll try that to start with.

Comment: What would be the event initiator in this case?! Cronjob is mandatory anyway.

Comment: Then accept this answer so that others will find this easily to solve their problem and do not forget to upvote as it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create a script in any language, let's say PHP, this script will just connect to the database, and execute the copy queries (grab and insert queries) whenever called.
Then, create a cronjob using Linux to execute the script on the needed schedule.
Sending Emails would be carried out by a similar technique.

Configure a cronjob: [setup a cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)
Copying data using PHP: [copying data using php](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-php-to-copy-tables-from-one-mysql-db-to-another/14679)

Comment: That's very useful.  I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL implements an [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) which can execute mysql stored procedures either once after a specific interval, once at a specific time or repeatedly at a specific interval; that might be of some use to you.

Comment: @Harris, this one is preferable.